# Read a time from file in java

Tags: java, time, duration

I am doing a work for the university and I have to read many lines from file a with that format:

3ld4R7  4:27    3475

Everything is correct, each line represents a song, the first string is the name, the second the duration and the third the popularity. However, I don't know exactly what type I can choose for the time. Then, I have to do many operations with the time (minutes, seconds, hours). I don't know if there is a class in Java libraries for that such as Time or something like that. Any help is thanked!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### java.time.Duration

The `Duration` class of java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is the class for — well, the name says it already. Unfortunately parsing a string like `4:27` into a `Duration` is not built-in. My preferred trick is:

```
    String durationString = "4:27";
    
    String isoString = durationString.replaceFirst("^(\\d+):(\\d+)$", "PT$1M$2S");
    Duration dur = Duration.parse(isoString);
    
    System.out.println(dur);
```

Output:

> PT4M27S

Read as a period of time of 4 minutes 27 seconds. The `Duration.parse` method requires a format known as ISO 8601, an international standard. And `Duration.toString()`, implicitly called when we print the `Duration`, produces ISO 8601 back. It goes like what you saw, `PT4M27S`. So in my code, the first thing I do is convert your input from the file to ISO 8601 format, which I then parse.

If you want to format the duration for display, for example back in the same format as in the file:

```
    System.out.format("%d:%02d%n", dur.toMinutes(), dur.toSecondsPart());
```

> 4:27

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Answer (score -2):

There is such a library in Java and more than one.
Try java.util.Date library and SimeplDateFormatter class to parse the date-time objects in a specific way according to the strings.

For example:

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy h:mm a");
Date date = (Date)formatter.parse(date)
```

Comment: It’s a *very* bad idea. A `Date` is for a point in time, not for a duration. Lots of errors have been caused (and asked about in Stack Overflow)  because of trying to misuse a `Date` for a duration. And `SimpleDateFormat` is a notorious troublemaker of a class. Fortunately both `Date` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated. Don’t use the,. Not even for dates, points in time for date formatting.

Comment: Good to know that but too bad that Date SimpleDateFormat are not deprecated, would have saved me a votedown...

Comment: Quite some old (though non-deprecated) methods of the standard library still accept a `Date` as argument. I suppose that this is why that haven’t dared deprecate the class just yet. (You can remove the downvote by deleting the answer; I recommend that no one uses it anyway.)